# ZF2 best practice for loading modules dynamically

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2

I'm trying to create a service, that helps the user to loading modules dynamically from system administration panel. That is my code:

```
if(!$this->isModuleInstalled($moduleName)) {
      $appConfigService = $this->getServiceManager()->get('ApplicationConfig');
      $appConfig = new Config($appConfigService, true);

      $modules = $config->modules->toArray();
      end($modules);
      $nextModuleKey = (key($modules) + 1);
      unset($modules);

      $config->modules->{$nextModuleKey} = $moduleName;

      $writter = new Writer\PhpArray();
      $writter->toFile(
            __DIR__ . '/../../../../../config/application.config.php', 
            $config->toArray()
      );
}
```

I think that is not the best practice for loading modules dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$configuration = $serviceManager->get('ApplicationConfig');
$configuration['modules'][] = 'ModuleName';
$serviceManager->setService('ApplicationConfig', $configuration);
$serviceManager->get('ModuleManager')->loadModules();
```